# When should I declare fields after methods in the source of a Java class?

Tags: java, coding-style

Some Java coding standards recommend declaring the fields of a class after all the methods.  Fields are an implementation detail, and are less important than any public method signatures, the theory goes.

However, I have - so far - found it difficult to adopt this practice.  I find that a quick glance of the member fields is a useful key to understanding how a class is approaching its responsibilities - which I generally already understand from the interfaces the class implements.  It is the methods which are the 'implementation details' when I'm reading the source.  And the source is to be laid-out for easy reading, right?

Like any advice, it's important to understand the tradeoffs.  I'm pretty clear on what I'm missing when I declare the fields last.  But can anyone enumerate what I really gain?

Comment: I usually declare all my member fields first before the member methods which I feel more readable. I don't see much difference declaring them last after the member methods which to some might be more readable. Don't think you are gaining/losing much - just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: I am the same as shams. I always declare fields as the first things inside the class declaration. I haven't heard of any justification for doing it otherwise. Pretty much all java code Ive seen does this, so I say its personal taste and making your code readable for others.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider:

- Your Java source file contains both interface and implementation. Both may be important to a reader.
- Anyone interested in only the public interface can look at the Javadocs for the class.
- Code generated by your Java IDE will likely default to fields before methods. New methods may be created at the bottom, which would shift fields-at-the-bottom into fields-in-the-middle.